# What did Bruce mean by 'same rules apply'?

Tags: dialogue, filth

In *Filth*, what did the last 'same rules apply' mean?

During the movie whenever he used the phrase, I understood this phrase by associating it with the consequence i.e. `the games' and not the actual reason for saying it. I just can't understand what is he actually trying to say with this phrase.

Moreover, at the end scene this phrase takes a whole different meaning as he goes on to kill himself. This action was entirely different than all the previous ones unless he was trying to be mean to the mother-son pair.